# Nearest neighbour analysis with higher elevation using QGIS

Tags: qgis, elevation, proximity, neighbour

How do I calculate the flow that goes through the rainfall drainage points under a railway?

I have two layers:

**DT**: Point layer with drainage information:  *DT_id* and *elevation*.

**ACA**: Point layer with de flowrate information: *ACA_id*, *flowrate* and *elevation*.

I need the flowrate that is upstream of each drainage point. Therefore I want to get the nearest ACA point to each DT point. But I need to add the condition that the nearest neibour has to be more elevated than the related DT point, in order to be sure that we selected the point that is upstream and not the one that is downstream.

I have tried using the "distance matrix" but I can't find how to impose this condition.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: select higher points and then look for the nearest neighbour?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome!
I have tried to improve my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ProcessX Plug-In](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ProcessX/) and run the algorithm **Join attributes by nearest with condition** from processing toolbox. Set it up the following:

[image]

*Disclaimer: I am the author of this Plug-In.*